# Why is the "find symbol error" occurring, and why is data set to null in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I created a Spring Boot project for a simple test and tried to verify it, but I couldn't resolve the issue, so I'm reaching out with a question.

The code below is essentially all there is:

```
//UserController.java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(@RequestBody User user) {

        //error: cannot find symbol
        //        System.out.println(user.getName());
        System.out.println(user.getName());
        System.out.println(user.getMessage());
        return "Hello ";
    }
}

// User.java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty
    private String message;
}
```

1. When I build, I get the error: cannot find symbol error at the `user.getName()` and `user.getMessage()` parts. These are clearly existing member variables, so why am I getting this error?
2. When testing the API, if there's no `@JsonProperty` in the User file, it gets set to null. I didn’t start the member variable with a capital letter, so why is this happening?

Comment: "when I build" How exactly are you building? Perhaps you don't have Lombok set up properly.

Comment: I have built using IntelliJ. Thanks for your comment. I will check for Lombok setup.

Comment: And I don't understand your second question. What's "the User file"? What is "it"?

Comment: "the User file" is User.java file.

Comment: Error 2. is related to error 1. Fix Lombok first. Jackson needs properly functioning setters to deserialize object.

Comment: User is a very common class name, make sure you have imported your User class. Also as others suggested, remove the Data annotation and make your own getters and setters if that works indeed it is a Lombok setup issue.

Comment: What IDEA are you using? Are the methods marked red?

Comment: I'm using IneliiJ and problems was solved. Lombok setting was the cause.